# check that a specific GPO setting exists for the domain

Tags: powershell, command, gpo

Is there a command (or powershell cmd) that I can run that will check a specific GPO setting exists for the domain? For example we need to check that the Guest account in Windows is disabled using GPO.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Group Policy is flexible and can apply different settings depending on the user/computer combination, so there is no way to check every single GPO combination in an entire domain.

You can check the settings being applied to a specific user/computer combination using either [Group Policy Results](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb456989.aspx) and [Group Policy Modeling](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771389(v=ws.11).aspx)

If your GPO configuration is simple enough you could check every combination, but it's not practically possible on large/complex domains.